# Is there any reason not to abandon "var"?

Tags: javascript, constants, var, let

In the process of learning JavaScript I learned that `Let` and `const` were introduced to fix the problems of `Var` regarding the global scope and hoisting and not giving an error if re-declared.

Now can I write the code completely without using `var` ? or should I know about them for now and wait till they becomes widely "acceptable"?

In other words, for the time being should I be worried about compatibility issues if I only used `let` and `const`?

Comment: `var` still has it's purposes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable.

Comment: You should be worried about compatibility issues with [let](http://caniuse.com/#search=let)  and [const](http://caniuse.com/#search=const) as both don't seem to be supported in IE10 and below and various other browsers.

Comment: @George transpilers exist ya know. Compatibility is nearly always a red-herring.

Comment: @George add IE11 too..https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ though you have shims to take care of that

Comment: In ES6 var still works that way, using functions as containers, **but** there are two new ways to declare variables: `const` and `let`.
`const` and `let` use `{` and `}` blocks as containers, hence "block scope". 
`let` works like `var` in the sense that its data is read/write.

Comment: few browsers support es6,  you should stick with the old version and keep using var.

Comment: I don't believe that "will I run into compatibility problems?" is an opinion-based question, so voting to re-open.

Comment: Well, you will *want* most variables that are explicitly in the global scope to be re-declarable. For those, `var` is still the best bet.

Comment: use typescript and set the target syntax?  write your code once, using `let` or `const`, and the ts compiler will either change it to `var` or keep it as-is depending on the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question directly - **no, you can't**, because of the compatibility issues, as @suraj kindly reminded us.

Having said that, in the modern JS development you are increasingly unlikely to use `var` as `let` and `const` have clear advantages, apart from some specific uses of `var` and will use either *BabelJS*, *TypeScript* or even now *Webpack 2* to transpile the code for backward compatibility as the production code will be shipped in *vanilla* JS. Modern IDEs, like WebStorm, will even lint your `var`'s by default in ES6 mode to change them to `let`.

Judging from the question, you are still in the process of studying JS and you are already asking the right questions, so I would recommend to use today `let` and `const` to utilize the advantages of ES6, but that would add the complexity of dealing with the transpilers. But if you are OK with that - this is the way to go.

Comment: the transpiler idea sound interesting to try !